# Raster colormap setting in ArcMap not honored in GP tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, mosaic, basic-license-level, colormap

I am working with digital versions of paper maps. Here is what I am attempting to do:

1. In ArcMap determine the value in a raster's colormap that is the
   undesired black mask / "no data" section.
2. Set that colormap value to no color.
3. Repeat this for all the rasters in an area.

At this point the rasters overlay just like I want them to. However, my final step is to use mosaic to new raster GP tool to create a new seamless raster.
Here is where everything goes sideways. The original value of the mask area will creep back in and overwrite values.

I tested doing a simple export from ArcMap after my colormap customization and the original colormap always sneaks back in. I can't seem to update the colormap permanently. I would like to avoid to have to laborious task of clipping out the area if possible.

**Please avoid bringing up Mosaic datasets I do not have access to an Advanced/Standard license.**

Comment: A colormap is just visual, it doesn't modify the data or any process that produces another output.  You may like to look at reclassifying your raster, or whether raster calculator would allow you to remove the color you don't want

Comment: In addition to being limited to basic level license I don't have the spatial analyst extension.

Answer (score 1):

As you have identified in your question your only ArcGIS Desktop options for doing this appear to be upgrading your core license or purchasing the Spatial Analyst extension.